# error in sending messages in webservice

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, remote-debugging

here is copy of log of messages processed by webservice

I arrived at a solution, i decided to move all variables from class to the do, get methods

Comment: doesn't sound thread safe then.

Comment: What kind of Web Service framework are you using? spring-mvc? You need to provide more details about your design to understand why it was overwritten

Comment: i am using soap, java webservice framework

Answer (score -1):

The webservice doesn't look to be thread safe.
Use keyword `synchronized` like:

```
public synchronized <return-type> <function-name>() {
    ....
}
```